# Dom U Installation on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: virtualization, xen

I am trying to add a DomU Operating system on Ubuntu 11.10.

I have successfully installed Xen.

Verified with

- xm info
- virsh-version

which returns this:

```
Compiled against library: libvir 0.9.2
Using library: libvir 0.9.2
Using API: Xen 3.0.1
Running hypervisor: Xen 4.1.
```

Now when I tried to install DomU it said:

> *unable to connect to 'localhost:8000':*

, in VMM.

So, I followed [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virt-manager/+bug/915954) bug link.

I could now start adding DomU. When adding DomU, in last stage, it gives the following error:

```
Unable to complete install: 'POST operation failed: xend_post: error
from xen daemon: (xend.err "Error creating domain: device model
'/usr/lib/xen/bin/qemu-dm' not found")'

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 44, in
cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 1899, in do_install
   guest.start_install(False, meter=meter)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/virtinst/Guest.py", line 1223, in start_install
    noboot)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/virtinst/Guest.py", line 1291, in _create_guest
    dom = self.conn.createLinux(start_xml or final_xml, 0)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 1686, in
createLinux
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateLinux() failed', conn=self) libvirtError: POST operation failed: xend_post: error from
xen daemon: (xend.err "Error creating domain: device model
'/usr/lib/xen/bin/qemu-dm' not found")
```

I tried following [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/914788) bug link that said, the bug is solved in the below package.

When I run `./configure` in this, I am getting an error:

```
checking for LIBXML... no 
checking libxml2 xml2-config >= 2.6.0 ...
configure: error: Could not find libxml2 anywhere (see config.log for details).
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Main error was:

(xend.err "Error creating domain: device model '/usr/lib/xen/bin/qemu-dm' not found")'

I checked and found, my folder is /usr/lib/xen-4.1/~

Where will the "add-DomU" script called from?

Answer (score 3):

That solution you posted isn't very robust, now you have two directories worth of binaries to maintain, one that isn't even under package control. A simple symlink: `ln -s /usr/lib/xen-4.1 /usr/lib/xen` would have sufficed, same thing for qemu.

Also, Serge Hallyn answered your build question in the [launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/914788/comments/5)

`sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxml2-utils`

Alternatively, you could install the updated libvirt package directly by using apt pinning.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I am new to Linux and on a learning curve, so I had to do that.

Comment: That's fine, please up vote and check mark the appropriate answers so we can close this issue out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, I have solved it...

For the error

```
 (xend.err "Error creating domain: device model '/usr/lib/xen/bin/qemu-dm' not found")
```

Copy the directory in the following location

```
cp /usr/lib/xen-4.1/* -r /usr/lib/xen/
```

After this there was an error

```
libvirtError: <Fault: 3>
```

So, I had to

```
cp -r /usr/share/qemu-linaro/ /usr/share/qemu
```

[Source](http://www.beyondlinux.com/2011/11/02/install-xen-4-1-and-setup-your-cloud-os-on-ubuntu-11-10/)